# ListView grid only show 1st column in React Native

Tags: listview, react-native, grid

I had a ListView with SectionHeader,GridLayout.

And after render(),I can only see the 1st column.It can only see 2nd,3rd columns **after I scroll ListView**.

Here is the img:

init:

[image]

after I scrolled:

[image]

I don't know why I can only see 2nd,3rd column after ListView scrolled.

Anyway to fix this?thank.:)

Comment: And there is some code:     listView: {
        // alignItems: 'flex-start',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
    },

Comment: <ListView
                    ref="listView"
                    contentContainerStyle={styles.listView}
                    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                    renderSectionHeader={this.renderSectionHeader}
                    renderRow={this.renderRow}
                    initialListSize={24}
                />

Comment: let dataSource = new ListView.DataSource({
            sectionHeaderHasChanged: (prevSectionData, nextSectionData) => true,
            rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => true,
        })

Comment: Share the way you are using to fill de ListView, but do it into the question so we can understand better. And share "renderRow" method too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, you need to set ListView prop pageSize to be the same number as number of columns, in your case it's 3.

Btw, I made a gridview component for react native that does this and more, you might want to check it out, https://github.com/pavlelekic/react-native-gridview